# ¿Cómo pasar un enumerado (enum) a una lista de strings (List<string>) o a un array de strings (string[])?

Tags: c#, enum

Pongamos que tengo por ejemplo el siguiente enumerado:

```
public enum TiposDeTurno{
    ALEATORIO,
    POR_ATRIBUTO,
    POR_JUGADOR
}
```

¿Cuál sería la mejor forma para pasarlo a un `List<string>` o a un `string[]`?

Comment: Como piensas emplearlo después de pasarlo a una de  esas listas.

Comment: Simplemente quiero mostrarlo en un [`popup`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.Popup.html) dentro del editor de Unity. Luego en función del indice seleccionado asignarlo en un objeto que tiene `TiposDeTurno tipoDeTurno`.

Comment: Entonces bajo esa perspectiva lo mas conveniente seria usar  `string[]` ya que puedes acceder al ndex directamente.

Comment: Si, realmente me da igual a cual, ya que pasar de una lista a un array o viceversa es fácil. Mi duda es cómo pasarlo a cualquiera de los dos.

Comment: Sin conocer cómo usar los tipo `Enum` en c#, en lo personal los hallo super útiles. En esta [pregunta&respuesta de SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/how-do-i-iterate-over-an-enum) muestran la manera de recorrer los valores del `Enum`, de pronto te sirve :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para poner los valores de tu `enum` en una lista tendrás que recorrer los valores con un `foreach` en donde usaras la función [GetValues()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues(v=vs.110).aspx), para obtener el Array de valores los cuales agregas  no sin antes convertirlos a `string`. Esta función sera independiente de la cantidad de valores que tengas.

```
//inicializo la lista
List<string> list = new List<string>();

// agrego el valor a la lista
foreach (var item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TiposDeTurno)))
{
    list.Add(item.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Es una buena solución, pero no me sirve porque quiero que sea algo totalmente independiente del enumerado, es decir, que si cambio el enumerado no tenga que cambiar esta clase. De esta forma tendria que volver a definir el array de strings.

Comment: @Wyrncael actualizo mi respuesta porque ya se por donde vas.

Comment: Ahora si, esto era lo que quería. Gracias! La doy por correcta pero voy a poner una forma mas sencilla que he descubierto gracias a tu respuesta y el comentario de @quinqui.

Comment: Misma respuesta algo actualizada: List<String> tiposList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TiposDeTurno)).Cast<TiposDeTurno>().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();

Answer (score 3):

No me gusta contestar mi propia pregunta, pero gracias al comentario de [quinqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/78037/quinqui) y la respuesta de [bercklyn Carlosviza](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/71259/bercklyn-carlosviza) he visto que era más fácil de lo que pensaba.

Simplemente, suponiendo que el enumerado se llama `TiposDeTurno`:

- Para pasarlo a un `string[]`:

  ```
  Enum.GetNames(typeof(TiposDeTurno);
  ```
- Y para pasarlo a un `List<string>`:

  ```
  Enum.GetNames(typeof(TiposDeTurno).ToList();
  ```